# Is there a way to forward a MediaStream to a server as an encoded video using HTML5 without using WebRTC?

Tags: html5-video, streaming, html5-audio, webm

I need to stream camera and microphone data from a browser to a server, ideally using a standard encoding like WebM. I would prefer to do this without using WebRTC because I don't need to negotiate any peer-to-peer connection. Is there a way to do this with HTML5 + JS? So far I've only found ways to record a stream on the client side, or forward a stream using WebRTC.

Comment: To answer my own question, it looks like this is possible using FFMPEG, WASM, and hls.js, specifically:

* use [ffmpeg.wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) to encode data from the camera and microphone as an RTSP stream: https://dev.to/tejasvi2/rtsp-stream-to-web-browser-using-ffmpeg-1cb
 * use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) to convert the RTSP stream to an HLS stream
 * then use a server-side library like GStreamer to decode the HLS stream: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/hls/hlsdemux.html